# Get datatype of each column in google spreadsheet

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I am using the google sheets APIs for node js
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

How can we access the datatype(number, decimal, string, date) of a column
in google spreadsheet using the above APIs?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct instruction from Sheets API aside from the [Reading values in Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading) guide. When you obtain the value of the cell assign it to a variable and make use of [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) Javascript function.

You may also try to make use of [getNumberFormats](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNumberFormats()) but this time using Google Apps Script. Those are the possible ways I can think of.

Comment: As I can see from the documentation Google Apps Script can only be used inside a browser. Is it possible to use it in server-side code?

Comment: I think Google Apps Script supports NodeJS as they have a [NodeJS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/nodejs).